# Segfault because of invalid pointer

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I'm builing a bin tree. Exmple: `key AAAA1.ETR, value 1`.

I'm reading files with this structure:

```
DataLength Block-SequenceNummer FLag   Start Data       Ende
4 Bytes    8 Bytes              1 Byte S     Datalength E
```

Data can be compressed or uncompressed(this is saved in flag).
Data contain more messages.

I'm getting this error:

```
*** glibc detected *** /home/frog/reader/unzipper: free(): invalid pointer: 0x00007ffff4c55108 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x7eb96)[0x7ffff758cb96]
/home/frog/reader/unzipper[0x401f2f]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xed)[0x7ffff752f76d]
/home/frog/reader/unzipper[0x400f59]
```

Backtrace:

```
(gdb) backtrace
#0  0x00007ffff7544425 in __GI_raise (sig=<optimized out>) at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:64
#1  0x00007ffff7547b8b in __GI_abort () at abort.c:91
#2  0x00007ffff758239e in __libc_message (do_abort=2, fmt=0x7ffff768c748 "*** glibc detected *** %s: %s: 0x%s ***\n") at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/libc_fatal.c:201
#3  0x00007ffff758cb96 in malloc_printerr (action=3, str=0x7ffff7689053 "free(): invalid pointer", ptr=<optimized out>) at malloc.c:5039
#4  0x0000000000401f1a in main () at u.c:373 (which is datap)
```

Here is what I tried so far:

```
#include <stdint.h> 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "zlib.h"
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <glib.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#define MYMAXSIZE 10000000
#define MAXFILESIZE 6000000
#define OBJNAME "8"
#define MSGTYPE "1"

const uint8_t broadcast[] = { 0x36, 0x33 };
const uint8_t status[] = { 0x34 };
const char dir0[]= "/home/frog/reader/feed.0/";
const char dir1[]= "/home/frog/reader/feed.1/";
const char dir2[]= "/home/frog/reader/feed.2/";
const char dir3[]= "/home/frog/reader/feed.3/";

typedef struct mtmheader_t
{
  unsigned char objName[20]; //8
  unsigned char msgType[3];     //1
}mtmheader_t;

typedef struct analyzer_t
{
  unsigned char *buff;
  size_t s;

}analyzer_t;


typedef struct analyzers_t
{
  analyzer_t anal1;
  analyzer_t anal2;
  analyzer_t anal3;
  unsigned char* seq;
}analyzers_t;

int readFilec(GTree *tree)
{
  FILE * fp = fopen("cfg/InstrumentList_FULL.csv", "rb" );
  char * line = NULL;
  size_t len = 0;
  ssize_t read;

  if (fp == NULL)
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  while ((read = getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1)
  {
    char *p1;
    int  *p2 = malloc(sizeof (int));
    printf("%s", line);
    p1 = strtok(line, "|");
    *p2 = atoi(strtok(NULL, "|"));
    g_tree_insert(tree, (gpointer) strdup( g_strdup(p1)), (gpointer)p2);
    //TrieAdd(&root, strdup(p1), p2);
    printf("-%s%d ", p1, *p2);

  }


  //exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);

}
int readFile( char *name,unsigned char *buffp)
{
  int fileSize = 0;
  //int n, i, j;
  printf("Opening file: \"%s\"\n", name);
  FILE *pFile = fopen(name, "rb");
  if(pFile == NULL)
  {
    printf("error: fopen()");
    return -1;
  }
  fseek(pFile, 0, SEEK_END);
  fileSize = ftell(pFile);
  printf ("%d\n", fileSize);
  rewind(pFile);
  //unsigned char *data = (unsigned char*) calloc(sizeof(unsigned char), fileSize + 20);
  int bytes = fread(buffp, 1, fileSize, pFile);
  if(ferror(pFile))
  {
    printf("error: fread()");
    return -1;
  }
  return bytes;
}

int processMTMHeader(unsigned char *datap, mtmheader_t *h,  unsigned char *endmmsgp)
{
  unsigned char *nextFsp;
  unsigned char *nextRsp;
  //nextRs
  size_t size = endmmsgp - datap;
  //Den Header komplett abarbeiten (bis GS (x1D) oder ETX (x03) kommt)
  //Byte lesen = RS (x1E)
  while ( (datap = (memchr(datap,  0x1E, size))) != NULL)//datap < endmmsgp)//=  strchr(datap,  '\x1E') != NULL )
  {
    datap++;

    //next Fs
    //Byte lesen = FS (x1C)
    nextFsp = memchr(datap, 0x1C,size);
    //Byte lesen = RS (x1C)
    nextRsp = memchr(datap, 0x1E, size);
    size = endmmsgp - nextRsp;
    if ( nextFsp - datap != 1)continue;
    if( *datap ==  0x38 )
    {
      //Objectnamen generieren() (Nur die ersten beiden Felder des Objectnamens verwenden)
      memcpy (h->objName, nextFsp+1, nextRsp - ( nextFsp+1)   );
      h->objName[ nextRsp - ( nextFsp+1)]='\0';
      //Abbruch der Schleife da ich jetzt den Objectnamen habe (Den Header komplett abarbeiten )
      return 1;
    }
    else if ( *datap == 0x31 )
    {
      memcpy (h->msgType, nextFsp+1, nextRsp - ( nextFsp+1)   );
      h->msgType[nextRsp - ( nextFsp+1)]='\0';
      if( (memcmp(h->msgType, broadcast, sizeof broadcast) != 0)  && (memcmp(h->msgType,status, sizeof( status))!=0 )) return 2;
    }
  }
  return -1;
}

int processData(unsigned char *datap, size_t size, GTree* t, analyzers_t *anals)
{
  int headerOk=0;
  unsigned char *nextmtmmsgp;
  unsigned char *endmmsgp   ;
  int * qsp;
  int s;

  while ( (datap = memchr (datap,  0x02, size))!= NULL )
  {
    //datap++;
    //printf("data\n%s", datap);
    endmmsgp = memchr (datap, 0x03, size);
    mtmheader_t h;
    headerOk = processMTMHeader(datap, &h, endmmsgp );
    int headersSize1 = 10;
    int headersSize2 = 10;
    int headersSize3 = 10;
    if (headerOk == 1)
    {
      if ((qsp = (int *) g_tree_lookup(t, h.objName)) != NULL )
      {
           s =  (endmmsgp - datap )+ 1;
           printf("found: %s %d\n", h.objName, *qsp);
           switch (*qsp)
           {
             case 1:
               memcpy(anals->anal1.buff + anals->anal1.s +  headersSize1, datap, s);
               anals->anal1.s = s + headersSize1 + anals->anal1.s ;
               headersSize1=0;
               break;
             case 2:
               memcpy(anals->anal2.buff + anals->anal2.s + headersSize2, datap, s);
               anals->anal2.s= s + headersSize2 + anals->anal2.s ;
               headersSize2=0;
               break;
             case 3:
               memcpy(anals->anal3.buff + anals->anal1.s + headersSize3, datap, s);
               anals->anal3.s= s + headersSize3 + anals->anal3.s ;
               headersSize3=0;
               break;
        }
      }
      else if (headerOk == 2)
      {
        memcpy(anals->anal1.buff + anals->anal1.s +  headersSize1, datap, s);
        anals->anal1.s = s + headersSize1 + anals->anal1.s ;
        headersSize1=0;

        memcpy(anals->anal2.buff + anals->anal2.s + headersSize2, datap, s);
        anals->anal2.s= s + headersSize2 + anals->anal2.s ;
        headersSize2=0;

        memcpy(anals->anal3.buff + anals->anal1.s + headersSize3, datap, s);
        anals->anal3.s= s + headersSize3 + anals->anal3.s ;
        headersSize3=0;
      }
    }
    datap++;
    printf("Name, type: %s %s\n",(char *) &h.objName,(char *) &h.msgType);
  }
  return -1;
}

gboolean iter_all(gpointer key, gpointer value, gpointer data) {
  int *s =  (int *)value;
  printf("\n%s%d \n", (char *)key, *s);
  return FALSE;
}

int writeFile(char *name,  unsigned char *buff, size_t *size, char *dir )
{
  FILE * pFile;
  char fullName[50];
  //fullName[0]='\0';
  //strcat(fullName, dir);
  //strcat(fullName, name);
  chdir (dir);  
  pFile = fopen ( name, "wb");
  //pFile = fopen (strcat ( strcat( strcat("feed.",anal), "/") , name ), "wb");
  fwrite (buff , sizeof(unsigned char), *size, pFile);
  fclose (pFile);
}


int writeFiles(char *name, analyzers_t *anals )
{
  if (anals->anal1.s > 10)writeFile(name, anals->anal1.buff, &anals->anal1.s, dir1);
  if (anals->anal2.s > 10)writeFile(name, anals->anal2.buff, &anals->anal2.s, dir2);
  if (anals->anal3.s > 10)writeFile(name, anals->anal3.buff, &anals->anal3.s, dir3);
}

int addHeader(size_t *start_size, size_t *end_size,unsigned char *buff, unsigned char *seq)
{
  *(buff+*start_size+ 9) ='S';
  uint32_t s = ((*end_size - *start_size) - 10);

  //size_t s_be = htonl(s);
  memcpy(buff+*start_size, &s, sizeof(s));
  memcpy(buff+4+*start_size, seq, 8 );
  buff[*start_size+8] = '\x00';
  *(buff + *end_size ) = 'E';

}

int main()
{
  analyzers_t anals;
  anals.anal1.buff = malloc(MYMAXSIZE);
  anals.anal2.buff = malloc(MYMAXSIZE);
  anals.anal3.buff = malloc(MYMAXSIZE);
  unsigned char *bytesp = malloc (MAXFILESIZE);
  unsigned char *datap = malloc (MYMAXSIZE);
  //char  dir[]     =   "feed.0/";

  DIR *dirp;
  char currDir[]=".";
  char parentDir[]="..";
  GTree* t = g_tree_new((GCompareFunc)g_ascii_strcasecmp);
  readFilec(t);
  g_tree_foreach(t, (GTraverseFunc)iter_all, NULL);
  struct dirent *direntp;
  if ((dirp = opendir(dir0)) == NULL)
  {
    perror("opendir");
    return 0;
  }
  struct stat status;
  chdir(dir0);
  int pos=0;
  uint32_t seq;
  size_t size;
  int flag;
  if (datap == NULL)return -1;
  unsigned char *datapor = datap;
  int compressOk=0;
  int loop =0;
  size_t oldSize1=0;
  size_t oldSize2=0;
  size_t oldSize3=0;

  while( (direntp = readdir(dirp)) != NULL)
  {
    if(strcmp(direntp->d_name, currDir) == 0)continue;
    if(strcmp(direntp->d_name, parentDir) == 0)continue;
    lstat(direntp->d_name, &status);
    if(S_ISDIR(status.st_mode))continue;

    compressOk=0;
    loop =0;
    pos=0;
    anals.anal1.s = 0;
    anals.anal2.s = 0;
    anals.anal3.s = 0;
    oldSize1 = 0;
    oldSize2 = 0;
    oldSize3 = 0;
    anals.anal1.buff[0]='\0';//anal1or;
    anals.anal2.buff[0]='\0';//anal2or;
    anals.anal3.buff[0]='\0';//al3or;
   readFile(direntp->d_name, bytesp);
   while(bytesp[pos+9] == 'S')
   {
     datap = datapor;

     printf("----------------------------\n");
     printf("|   LOOP %d, POSITION %d   |\n", loop, pos);
     printf("----------------------------\n\n");

     size =  ntohl(bytesp[pos+0]<<24| bytesp[pos+1]<<16| bytesp[pos+2]<<8| bytesp[pos+3]);
     if (bytesp[pos+10+ size]!='E')
     {
       pos = pos + 11 + size;
       continue;
     }
     seq = ntohl(bytesp[pos+4]<<24| bytesp[pos+5]<<16| bytesp[pos+6]<<8| bytesp[pos+7]);
     anals.seq = bytesp +pos+4;
     //Flag lesen
     flag = bytesp[pos+8];
     if( bytesp[pos+8]=='\x01')
     {
       size_t size_uncompress = MYMAXSIZE * sizeof(unsigned char);
       compressOk = uncompress(datap, &size_uncompress, &bytesp[pos+10], size);
       datap[size_uncompress]='\0';
       printf ("%zu %zu :\n", size, size_uncompress) ;
     }
     else
     {
       datap = &bytesp[pos+10];
       //datap[pos+10+ size] ='\0';
     }
     printf("---------------------------- \n");
     printf("|     Message as String:    |\n");
     printf("---------------------------- \n");
     printf("%s\n\n\n", datap);
     processData(datap, size, t, &anals);
     pos = pos + 11 + size;

     if (anals.anal1.s > oldSize1 )
     {
       addHeader( &oldSize1,&anals.anal1.s, anals.anal1.buff, anals.seq );
       anals.anal1.s++;
       oldSize1 = anals.anal1.s;

     }
     if (anals.anal2.s > oldSize2 )
     {
       addHeader( &oldSize2,&anals.anal2.s, anals.anal2.buff, anals.seq );
       anals.anal2.s++;
       oldSize2 = anals.anal2.s;

     }
     if (anals.anal3.s > oldSize3 )
     {
       addHeader( &oldSize3,&anals.anal1.s, anals.anal3.buff, anals.seq );
       anals.anal3.s++;
       oldSize3 = anals.anal1.s;

     }

     loop++;

   }
   writeFiles(direntp->d_name,  &anals);
 }
 free(datap);
 free(bytesp);
 free(anals.anal1.buff);
 free(anals.anal2.buff);
 free(anals.anal3.buff);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In function `readFilec()`, `free(line);` You've allocated memory dynamically to pointer `p2` and trying to free a char pointer `line` which is incorrect.

Comment: there is a condition.  I have asked about invalid poiter to datap at the very end.